# use heroku as dev environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have one problem, I have now laptop and I have no opportunity to install ubuntu.
Let's say that laptop is not mine, I am somewhere out of the city, and the owner is quite paranoid about installing something else besides windows.
And I can't use virtual machine, cause I get strange errors conneted to laptop hardware.
But I need to programm some website, actually I need to programm some kind of forum.
So I want to use some forum gem.
But the thing is that I tried to install rails and get it running on windows and gave up cause it's  really a pain
So is there some way to programm everthing remotely  deploying to heroku?

Comment: [Cloud9](https://c9.io/) — Please delete this question as it is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd recommend reading "[ask]" and the pages it links to, and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421. Your question is very broad.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is set up to use git for updating the site remotely. You can use windows but you will need to install Rails and Ruby. I don't think there is a solution for you involving just Heroku. Maybe Digital Ocean since you get a full on operating system and then update to Heroku from there if need be.